# Verify Error After Using unpack200

Tags: java, compression, japplet, jarsigner

I got problem when trying to load a jar that has been compressed using [pack200](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/pack200.html). I found the error that my jar file cannot be verified after I use `unpack200`.

Here is the scenario:

1. Create keystore `keytool -keystore key -genkey -alias hj`
2. Sign the jar `jarsigner -keystore key HelloJApplet.jar hj`
3. Compress that jar file: `pack200 HelloJApplet.jar.pack.gz HelloJApplet`
4. Uncompress and rename: `unpack200 HelloJApplet.jar.pack.gz HelloJAppletUnpack.jar`
5. Verify the jars: `jarsigner -verify HelloJApplet.jar` and `jarsigner -verify HelloJAppletUnpack.jar`

For the `HelloJApplet.jar` it showed `jar verified.` and for `HelloJAppletUnpack.jar` it showed an error `jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for org/ff/ffw/app/
HelloJApplet.class`

**Anything wrong with what I do so far?** *Please correct me what point that I'm missing or wrong.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sign a pack200 jar, you need to pack+unpack (i.e. repack), sign and pack again. see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Pack200#Compression_and_Signing or http://www.java.net/node/679859

```
pack200 --repack b.jar a.jar
sign b.jar
```

(p.s. there was a bug in 5.0 and fixed in 5.0u1. upgrade if needed)

Comment: It's worked. How can I check my pack200 version? And how to upgrade that?

Comment: no, `--repack` once is by design. (repack twice was a bug long fixed)

Answer (score 1):

**Not the case on WINDOWS**. I just confirmed a bug with pack200.

On Windows you must run the `pack200.exe --repack` command **twice**. For example:

```
pack200.exe --repack A.jar
pack200.exe --repack B.jar A.jar
sign B.jar
pack200.exe B.pack.gz B.jar
```

In addition, **you must have 2 arguments for the second repack**. The following sequence will **FAIL**:

```
pack200.exe --repack A.jar
pack200.exe --repack A.jar
>Skipping because already repacked: A.jar
sign A.jar
pack200.exe A.pack.gz A.jar
PACKED JAR IS STILL BAD
```